# Escaping characters in python just once (single backlash)

Tags: python, escaping

I want to escape a string from this:

```
str1 = "this is a string (with parentheses)"
```

to this:

```
str2 = "this is a string \(with parentheses\)"
```

That is, a single `\` escape character at the parentheses. This is to be fed to another client which needs to escape these characters and will only work with a single escaping slash.

For simplicity I focus below on the opening parentheses only, i.e. changing from `'('` to `'\('`
So far I tried:

1. replace

   ```
   str1.replace("(", "\(")
   'this is a string \\(with parentheses)'
   ```
2. sub

   ```
   re.sub( "\(", "\(", str1)
   'this is a string \\(with parentheses)'
   ```
3. Escape dictionary with raw string

   ```
   escape_dict = { '(':r'\('}
   "".join([escape_dict.get(char,char) for char in str1])
   'this is a string \\(with parentheses)'
   ```

Whatever the case I always get double backlash. Is there a way to get only one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing the string representation with the string *value*. The double backslash is there to make the string round-trippable; you can paste the value back into Python again.

The actual string itself has just **one** backslash.

Take a look at:

```
>>> '\\'
'\\'
>>> len('\\')
1
>>> print '\\'
\
>>> '\('
'\\('
>>> len('\(')
2
>>> print '\('
\(
```

Python escapes the backslash in string literal representations to prevent it from being interpreted as an escape code.